# URL Routing: Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have been working on laravel and have been doing some routing. I was just wondering on what is the difference between writing the route as:

```
route::get('roles/{id}/edit',rolesController@edit);
```

versus

```
route::get('roles/edit/{id}',rolesController@edit);
```

One difference is clearly visible and that is the placement of the id variable. Can't figure out any other reason. Please provide an explanation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the actual look of the URL, there's no real difference as far as the framework is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's the matter of preference when using any of this. Maybe, for example, if you are giving options of editing the user profile and posts, this might come handy as both are different routes, technically

Answer (score 0):

No difference. It depends on you how you would like to build your routes. But try to user best practices which laravel creator recommend (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers).

And also i want take your attention on how you called your controller. You should use CamelCase for naming your files (https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference, but you might want to look in [reosource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) routes and controller. Basically, laravel framework automatically creates routes and methods for controllers that you might need in your project. For example:
If you create a contoller like this:

```
php artisan make:controller RolesController --resource
```

and create a resource route like this:

```
Route::resource('/roles', 'RolesController ');
```

framework automatically crates this routes for you:

```
Verb          Path                         Action  Route Name
GET           /roles                       index   roles.index
GET           /roles/create                create  roles.create
POST          /roles                       store   roles.store
GET           /roles/{roles}               show    roles.show
GET           /roles/{roles}/edit          edit    roles.edit
PUT|PATCH     /roles/{roles}               update  roles.update
DELETE        /roles/{roles}               destroy roles.destroy
```

So you don't have to make your own routes and ask yourself if they are correct or not. Look into laravel official documentation for more info about this.